# Can Apple Mail perform a server side IMAP search (and if so, how)?

Tags: mail.app, search, imap

I have a dovecot IMAP server that is configured with full-text-search, including Apache Tika with OCR support. This allows me to search within attachments, including image attachments. Using dovecot tooling, I can confirm IMAP search is finding text correctly within attachments.

In a test account set up for this purpose, containing various attachments containing known strings, Apple Mail returns zero responses to search queries I know do exist on the server.

The searches that do work appear to be the contents of a Pages document, but nothing processed on the server side.

Is it possible to tell Apple Mail to use server side IMAP search, and if so, how?

Comment: You might try Outlook as it appears to have more robust search capabilities.

Comment: Apple Mail only does local search. I guess Apple Mail search is working if Mail is finding text in attachments from Pages. For attachment content it is relying on Spotlight indexing - which is fine for most text attachment, but may be problematic for text inside image attachments.

Comment: @Allan Outlook it turns out has no search capabilities, deferring the whole problem to the server. Paradoxically this is what we want, but we were hoping to do this without switching clients.